# Android dont print ARGB color like #c01c2112

Tags: android, colors

Does `Android` not supporting printing the color like `#c01c2112` with the format ARGB? It display error because of invalid color.

This part of my code is Store `1` and `0` into the `arraylist`.

```
 ArrayList<String>arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
 for(int a = 0; a < bitmap1.getWidth(); a++){
     for(int b = 0; b < bitmap1.getHeight(); b++){
         String a1 = String.valueOf(arrayInput1[a][b]);
         String a2 = String.valueOf(arrayInput2[a][b]);
         String a3 = String.valueOf(arrayInput3[a][b]);
         String a4 = String.valueOf(arrayInput4[a][b]);
         String a5 = String.valueOf(arrayInput5[a][b]);
         String a6 = String.valueOf(arrayInput6[a][b]);
         String a7 = String.valueOf(arrayInput7[a][b]);
         String a8 = String.valueOf(arrayInput8[a][b]);
        arrayList.add(a1+a2+a3+a4+a5+a6+a7+a8); 
        // Store 1110001 into ArrayList
        }
    }//End of nested For
```

Then here is the part to pass the data to an `array`.

```
 String [] hexArrayRed = new String[arrayList.size()];
 arrayList.toArray(hexArrayRed);
```

Then I input myself the `#ff` and the `0000` and combine with the data as I convert the data to `hexadecimal` value type. It is working fine here.

```
 for(int a = 0; a < hexArrayRed.length; a++){
     int dec = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(arrayList.get(a)),2);
     String hexString = Integer.toString(dec, 16);
     String alpha = "#ff";
     String behind = "0000";
     hexArrayRed[a] = alpha+hexString+behind;
     /*
        Red Hexadecimal Value --> #ff _ _ 0000
     */
 }
```

Then there is the problem.

```
 QRCodeWriter qwRed = new QRCodeWriter();
 try {
      HashMap<EncodeHintType, Object> hints = new HashMap<>();
      hints.put(EncodeHintType.CHARACTER_SET, "utf-8");
      hints.put(EncodeHintType.MARGIN, 2);

      BitMatrix matrix = qwRed.encode(finalText,
           BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE,
           bitmap1.getWidth(),
           bitmap1.getHeight(),
           hints);

      //START OF RED
      final Bitmap newBitmapRed = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                bitmap1.getWidth(),
                bitmap1.getHeight(),
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
      );

     int counter1 = 0;
     for (int a = 0; a < bitmap1.getWidth(); a++) {
         for (int b = 0; b < bitmap1.getHeight(); b++) {
              //int c = 0;
              int[] color = new int[hexArrayRed.length];
              color[counter1] = Color.parseColor(hexArrayRed[counter1]); //Error is right here
              int d = matrix.get(a,b)? color[counter1]: Color.WHITE;
              newBitmapRed.setPixel(a,b,d);
              counter1++;
           }
    }
    //END OF RED
```

Then I get the error of printing the unknown color.

```
 Process: kopilim.scs.prototyping, PID: 9890
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown color
```

Is it the `Android` dont support color like `#f212cc12` some sort like this the ARGB color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code of converting from binary to decimal to hex works fine, except for one tiny part.

The problem is related to this part of your code:

```
String hexString = Integer.toString(dec, 16);
```

The problem with using `Integer.toString()` is that it'll give you the integer as a String, without the extra 0 padding.

What I mean by this is, for example: if your binary String was `00000111`. Using `Integer.parseInt("00000111", 2);` would give you a decimal int of 7.

Finally, using `String hexString = Integer.toString(7, 16);` would give you a String of "7".

Therefore, when you plug that value into your `hexArrayRed[a]`, instead of plugging it in as `#AARRGGBB`, you're plugging it in as `#AARGGBB` which is an improper format.

So to fix this, you simply have to check the length of `hexString` to see if it only has a size of 1. If it is, append an extra 0 to the front of it when you create your full hex string.

Comment: the `hexString` in my case is contain 2 alphanumeric value only which it make sense to `ARGB` format. For example, the 1st index of `arraylist` the value is 21. So the value will be `#ff210000`

Comment: My apologies, I misunderstood your code before. I've relooked at your code and I believe I've found the cause of your issue. I modified my answer with the new solution, please check to see if it helps.